# get array if array contains id mongoose

Tags: arrays, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema

It is a tricky one. I thought I could use $in, but after querying, it wasn't where I was looking for.

This is my schema

```
var gameSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    state: {
        type: String,
        default: "invited"
    },
    finished: {
        type: Boolean,
        default: false
    },
    players: {
        type: [{
            type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
            ref: 'users'
        }],
        required: true,
    },
    scores: [scoreSchema],
    chat : [chatSchema]
});
```

The request I'm trying to make is the following, I send a user Id, if the players array contains this Id, return the other id (the array will always have length 2) in the array.

The context is that you can lookup against whom you have played before.

This is what I had, but "players" should be an array and it's not games that I want to return, so

```
exports.getFriends = function(id, cb){
    gameSchema.find({ id: { "$in": "players"} }, function(err, games){
        if(err){
            return cb(err, null);
        }
        else{
            return cb(null, games);
        }
    });
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try this?

```
exports.getFriends = function(id, cb){
    gameSchema.find({ players: id }, function(err, games) {
        if (err) {
            return cb(err);
        }
        const players = games.map(game => game.players);
        const mergedPlayers = [].concat.apply([], players);
        const mappedPlayers = mergedPlayers.map(String); // convert ObjectIds to strings for comparisons.
        const idString = String(id);
        const filteredPlayers = mappedPlayers.filter(player => player !== idString);
        const uniquePlayers = filteredPlayers.filter((player, index, arr) => arr.indexOf(player) === index);
        return cb(null, uniquePlayers);
    });
};
```

I'm operating under the assumption that you want an array of the unique player ids that are *not* the player id you passed in. I kept the vars split apart instead of chaining all of the array methods, in an attempt to improve readability.

Comment: this should work. I believe you can query for specific values in array properties the same way you query for a String, etc.

Comment: Yup. It's a bit odd, in my opinion. My first instinct was to try to use a `$contains` operator, but I don't think that exists in mongo.

Comment: It is but I love how easy it is to query for things in MongoDB. :)

Comment: but how do I fetch the other id from the array? or even just the array players, so I can letter extract distinct id's

Comment: What do you want the output to be? An array of every player in each of those games which is not the id you passed in?

Comment: an array of the player.id's which where in the same array as the id that I passed as paramater, so if the arrays are {1,2},{3,7}{3,5} and I pass 3, I want an array of {7,5}, if I pass 1 I want {2}

Comment: just came home from work so couldn't test it earlier